# What's the right way to trigger on multiple conditions in a WPF Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles, multidatatrigger

My WPF application has a `DataGrid` control in it.  I have a default custom style for the `DataGridRow` class which works well.  However, for this one particular `DataGrid` on this one particular screen, I need a different custom style.

The Items in each row have a `bool` property that, when set, I want to display that row with a different foreground and background color.  However, when the row is selected AND when that property is set, I want a different foreground and background color to show that it's selected AND the property is set to true.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="CameraStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataBackground}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsInLiveMode}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsInLiveMode}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background"  Value="DarkOrange" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DataBorder}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="DarkRed" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This gives me a "Binding must be non-null" error, which I think is happening because there is no `Binding` property on the first condition in the MultiDataTrigger.

What is the correct way to write this in XAML?

EDIT:

After trying nemesv's & Rachel's answer, the code now compiles and runs.  However, the colors I've chosen for the IsSelected = true and IsInLiveMode = true case are not showing up.  Here's what I have now:

```
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="CameraStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource DataBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextForeground}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsInLiveMode}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsInLiveMode}" Value="False" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{DynamicResource DataBackgroundSelected}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DataBorder}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{DynamicResource DataForegroundSelected}" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsInLiveMode}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background"  Value="DarkOrange" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource DataBorder}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="DarkRed" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Any ideas on why the case in question isn't working?

Comment: Are the other two cases especially the case `IsInLiveMode=true` and  `IsSelected=false` working correctly?

Comment: I did a quick test with your triggers and they work fine, however the background color does not always get inherited by the `DataGridCell`. The easiest way to change that is to use an implicit style for `DataGridCell` that sets the `Background` to `Transparent`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your assumptution is correct regarding the missing binding.

From MSDN [MultiDataTrigger.Conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.conditions.aspx):

> For a MultiDataTrigger, each condition in the collection **must set both
>   the Binding and Value** properties.

You can solve this using [RelativeSource Self](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553635%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to refer yourself in the binding:

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
         Path=IsSelected}" Value="True" />
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsInLiveMode}" Value="True" />
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

Comment: nemesv:  Thanks, that at least doesn't throw any errors.  There is still a problem.  Please look at my edits to my original question.

Answer (score 8):

You're using a `MultiDataTrigger`, which is still a `DataTrigger` and expects a binding

Switch `Property="IsSelected"` in your `Condition` to

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
           Value="True" />
```

Comment: Rachel: I wish I could check off yours and @nemesv's answers as the correct answer, because you're both right.  But nemesv did answer first, so he gets the checkmark.

Comment: @TonyVitabile That's fine, I think his answer is better anyways because of the MSDN links, and already gave him a +1 for it :)